# Define size "table" of dynamic values

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, keil, 8051

(Using Keil µVision 5 - Ax51, device: AT89C51AC3)

I'm trying to "read" the values (value by value) of a table, moving them in the accumulator. My actual code looks in the following way:

```
ORG 0h

MOV dptr, #40h

loop:   
    MOV A, #0
    MOVC A, @A+DPTR
    INC DPTR
    INC R0
    CJNE R0, #table_end - table_start, loop

ORG 40h
table_start:        DB 1,2,4
table_end:

END
```

I would like to exit the loop, as soon as the values of my "table" have been all moved once in the accumulator. It works, but if I add a value manually, the "size" of my "table" doesn't update (subtracting the end and start labels). Any idea how to update the size/length of my "table" if I "add" a value manually after the defined byte '4' (as example)?

P.s: With manually I mean after I started the code (in my case, during the Debug Session).

I would appreciate any idea and suggestion!

Edit 1:

```
ORG 0h

MOV dptr, #40h

loop:   
    MOV A, #0
    MOVC A, @A+DPTR
    INC DPTR
    INC R0
    MOV R1, #table_end - table_start
    CJNE R0, #table_end - table_start, loop

ORG 40h
table_start:        DB 1,2,4
table_end:

END
```

Comment: Put the table size into a register, and update that register too when you mess with the table.

Comment: I've already tried it. That's exactly the problem. How can I update the register when I mess with the table? I found no solution. As I said, I add values in the Debug Session.

Comment: Your debugger should be able to change registers.

Comment: Of course I can change register's values. But when I add a value "to my table", the result of  #table_end-table_start still contains the size of the table without considering the values that I've added manually during the debug session, even if I jump to the calculation of #table_end-table_start.

Comment: That's why I said to put it into a register...

Comment: Take a look at the "Edit 1". When I run the code (during the debug session), the value of R1 doesn't change if I add values manually (to the table). Maybe I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: Of course it does not change, we have just discussed that **you** can change it in the debugger. Obviously the `cjne` should be using `r1` not the constant.

Comment: I know that the cjne should be using R1, it was just for testing. My question is, how can I update the register automatically if I add a value?

Comment: You can't, how could you? You add the value to the table manually during debugging, so you need to update the size in the same way, manually. You could use a terminator in your array then the code could determine the length.

Comment: That is what I wanted to know. Thanks for the answer. With "a terminator" do you mean a number that I then confront to determinate the lenght?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Perfect. I thought exactly the same think, but maybe it was possible to update the register automatically. If you answer the topic, I can accept your answer. Thank you very much! @Jester